# Parse html and javascript using Jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm parsing an HTML string that contains html tags and javascript tags using the following

```
public Document parse(String content) {
    return Jsoup.parse(content, "", Parser.xmlParser());
  }
```

The problem is that javascript elements have been included only in one line.

Also, I've try with

```
public Document parse(String content) {
    return Jsoup.parse(content, "", Parser.htmlParser());
  }
```

and that works fine for Javascript... but HTML elements have been included without end tag. Ex:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../static/public/img/favicon.ico" data-th-remove="all"></link>
```

has been parsed like

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../static/public/img/favicon.ico" data-th-remove="all">
```

That doesn't work when I run my application.

How can I fix that? Is there any way to parse HTML and Javascript together using JSOUP?

**NOTE**: I've just create the following issue on JSOUP gitHub https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/774

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `link` element does not have a closing tag in HTML. It only occurs in the header. See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link for explanations.

So JSoup behaves as expected when you use the `Parser.htmlParser()`

Cab you explain in more detail, why you can't process an unclosed `link` tag?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Finally, the problem was that I've been using Thymeleaf 2.1.5 provided by Spring IO Platform. That Thymeleaf version uses an XML parser to parse the .html file, so it needs to have all tags with its own end tag. 

Updating to Thymeleaf 3.0 and using `Parser.htmlParser()` I've solved the problem.

To see a detailed explanation about the solution check the gitHub issue https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/774 . Regards and thanks for your help.